# How to interpret the date time pattern in XSD?

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I have the following regex pattern in XSD, and I couldn't  figure the right format, and my data was failed by the validation, can someone help me on this?

they all failed

```
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"> 
      <xsd:pattern value="(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(T(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2})(.\d{6})(\+|\-)(\d{4})"/>
</xsd:restriction
```

Here are what I have tried:

2013-04-26 17:12.000000+0000

2013-04-26T17:12.000000+0000

2013-04-26 17:12.000000-0000

2013-04-26'T'17:12.000000+0000

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the repetition. `(:[0-5][0-9]){2})` says that you need a pattern of `:[0-5][0-9]` (which is placed into a capturing group, so it's now a unit) two times (`{2}`).

These match

```
2015-01-01T17:12:27.000000+0000
2013-04-26T17:12:00.000000+0000
```

The time values are made up of `T`, which indicates time, followed by a two digit hour, `:`, followed by two digit minutes, `:`, followed by two digit seconds, `.` followed by six digit milliseconds, and then ending in a `+` or `-` followed by a four digit time offset.

Answer (score 0):

solved

something in the following format:

2016-04-23T09:09:09.000000+0000

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with answering your own question, @KenWhite already provided a fuller answer of this.  It would be best to accept his answer.